# Filtering data reactively in choropleth ggplot2 map with Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am creating a choropleth map with reactive filters using shiny. The current version shows the year slicer but without the map. I have gone through several iterations and was able to create the map outside of the shiny ui.

Here is the example dataset:
[Rent.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aor4SxYjDbTuV0MgKkJ2xHm7c2WE7Fuq/view?usp=sharing)

Here is an image of the current output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cljg.png)

Thanks for your help!

Here are the install packages I am using.

```
# Install packages
install.packages(c("geojsonio", "ggplot2", "tidyverse", "dplyr", "viridis", "sf", "mapview", "leaflet", "shiny"))
library(geojsonio)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis)
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
```

Read data tables and Join them.

```
# Read the geojson file
barcelona_barri <- geojson_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martgnz/bcn-geodata/master/barris/barris.geojson",  what = "sp")
barcelona_barri

#change data to readable data frame
bcn_barri <- tidy(barcelona_barri)

# Change id to numeric to complete join
bcn_barri$id <- as.numeric(as.character(bcn_barri$id))

# Read rent csv
rent <- read.csv("rent.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

# Full join the data tables
bcn_barri = bcn_barri %>% 
  full_join(. , rent, by=c("id" = "codi_barri"))

# Set factor
bcn_barri$any <- factor(bcn_barri$any)
```

Table is ready for Shiny app.

```
# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Data Selector"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for years
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("year", "Year",
                  choices = c("All", levels(bcn_barri$any)),
                  selected = "All"
      )
    ),
    
    #show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot", width = "75%", height = "400px"))
    
  )
)

# Define server logic required 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  fc <- reactive({
    barri <- bcn_barri
    if(input$year != "All") barri <- bcn_barri %>% filter(any == input$year)
    
    barri  
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    #get the data
    barri <- fc()
    
    #generate a map
    ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data = barri, aes(fill = avg_monthly_rental_euros, x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
      theme_void() +
      labs(
        title = "Barcelona Rental Prices by Neighborhood",
        subtitle = "Average Rent Costs",
        caption = "Data: Open Data BCN | Copyright (c) 2019 Martín González"
      ) +
      theme(
        text = element_text(color="#22211d"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color=NA),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color=NA),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color=NA),
        
        plot.title = element_text(size=12, hjust = 0.01, color = "#4e4d47", margin = margin(b = -0.1, t = 0.4, l = 2, unit = "cm")),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size=10, hjust = 0.01, color = "#4e4d47", margin = margin(b = 0.1, t = 0.43, l=2, unit="cm")),
        plot.caption = element_text(size=9, color = "#4e4d47", margin = margin(b = 0.3, r=-99, unit = "cm")),
        legend.key.size = unit(10, 'mm'),
        
        legend.position = c(0.3, 0.04)
      ) +
      coord_map()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is it just that you have a typo in the definition for `ui`?  Your code has `ui <- fluidpage(...`, but the function has a capitalization and should read `ui <- fluidPage(...`.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. I worked that and a few other issues I spotted diving into it again but... to no avail. I am now not getting any errors but now it is only giving me that app page without the chart and without the ability to select different years.

Comment: Is the "`any`" column in your dataset a factor?  If it's reading as a character vector, then `levels(rent$any)` is going to give you `NULL`.  You can try `rent$any <- factor(rent$any)` after defining `rent` and see if that fixes things.  The fact that you don't get anything in the dropdown as levels from `rent$any` is hinting that might be the issue.

Comment: That worked! And it also made me realize I was referencing the wrong data frame initially. Either way, I updated the code to reflect the correct data frame. I also tested the the initial map on its own with success. However, now the app appears to be stalling:/

Comment: Glad I helped make some progress, but at this point you'll have to share an example dataset to try to get your problem to be reproducible to help much further.  Does it always stall, and what do you have when stalling?  Do you see the app environment and inputs + plot area?  Are you getting errors in the console when the app is running?  Are you able to get a plot when "All" is selected?  This type of debugging info can also help.

Comment: Honestly, It was stalling after running the app several times in a row, so I think this may have caused some issues??? After, copying the code to a new script, I was able to get the the output in the link I provided in my update of the question without any errors. I also just added an example data set. Thanks again!